# How to predict a continuous dependent variable that expresses target class probabilities?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, regression

My samples can either belong to class 0 or class 1 but for some of my samples I only have a probability available for them to belong to class 1. So far I've discretized my target variable by applying a threshold i.e. all y >= t I assigned to class 1 and I've discarded all samples that have non-zero probability to belong to class 1. Then I fitted a linear SVM to the data using scitkit-learn.

Of cause this way I through away quite a bit of the training data. One idea I had was to omit the discretization and use regression instead but usually it's not a good idea to approach classification by regression as for example it doesn't guarantee predicted values to be in the interval [0,1].

By the way the nature of my features x is similar as for some of them I also only have probabilities for the respective feature to be present. For the error it didn't make a big difference if I discretized my features in the same way I discretized the dependent variable.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to approximate this using sample weighting - assign a sample to the class which has the highest probability, but weight that sample by the probability of it actually belonging. Many of the scikit-learn estimators allow for this.

Example:

X = [1, 2, 3, 4] -> class 0 with probability .7 would become X = [1, 2, 3, 4] y = [0] with sample weight of .7 . You might also normalize so the sample weights are between 0 and 1 (since your probabilities and sample weights will only be from .5 to 1. in this scheme). You could also incorporate non-linear penalties to "strengthen" the influence of high probability samples.

Comment: I always duplicate the training set, then use the probability as the sample weight for positive and (1 - probability) as sample weight for negative.

Comment: How close does this get to writing out a cross entropy function with the probabilities instead of hard 0/1 targets? (I have not a single sheet of paper to write it out right now, but will try as soon as I do)

Comment: @larsmans if I am not completely hallucinating, duplicating the training set, setting the target variable for the first copy to 1 and for the second copy to -1 and then sample weighting the way you indicate, leads exactly to optimizing the cross entropy for two targets and soft assignment.

Comment: I think this could work. Intuitively it make sense to use sample specific weights. If we just add samples to the positive class I think we discard the probability of those samples to belong to the negative class. 
If this proves to minimize cross-entropy this would be a neat justification for that data transformation.
@Kyle: I looked through the scikit-learn classifier but it seems that actually just a few support sample specific weights e.g. decision trees and ensemble methods building on decision trees. liblinear only supports weights through libsvm-tools which is not in scikit-learn.

Comment: @eickenberg It's not too hard to prove :) It does mess with the regularization, though, so that should be re-tuned.

Comment: Yeah, I had to write it down on paper to be sure though, leading to my 2-part comment. As for regularization, the last time I looked, liblinear penalized the intercept, so it's all messed up anyway ... :)